# How to get the the signature type from the function pointer type?

Tags: c++, c++17

Say I have the following function pointer typedef:

```
    using FType = int(*)(int,int);
```

How can I construct a `std::function` object using the signature of `FType`?

For example if FType were defined using `using FType = int(int,int)`, it could be done by `std::funtion<FType> func = ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using FType = int(*)(int,int);
std::function<std::remove_pointer_t<FType>> func;
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::function` can do [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), hence this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using FType = int(*)(int,int);

int foo(int,int) {}

int main(){
    FType x = &foo;
    auto f = std::function(x);
}
```

Comment: Note that CTAD only works in C++17 onwards.